# How to map multiple subdomains to a single cloudfront distribution with Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I want these 2 subdomains: `beta.mysite.io` and `mysite.io` to point to my single cloudfront distribution. Currently `beta.mysite.io` has an `A` record and a `AAAA` record pointing to `afdsafa.cloudfront.net`(cloudfront CNAME) but when I add `A` records and `AAAA` records for the domain `mysite.io` it doesn't work. I am not sure what I could be missing

I tried adding `A` records and `AAAA` records to point to `afdsafa.cloudfront.net` (cloudfront CNAME)

I want to the 2 subdomains to resolve to the same cloudfront distribution

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* ... please explain in what sense it does not work.  This isn't sufficient detail.

Comment: It gives me a cloudfront 403 error

Comment: Did you add the new hostname to the "Alternate Domain Names" box in the CloudFront console?

Comment: Yes I have the CNAME(Alternate domain names) on cloudfront pointing to beta.mysite.io